# qml file and app.js not found

Tags: application-development, qt, html5

I am a newbie in ubuntu app development. I am going through the tutorials in developer.ubuntu.com. The thing is when I created a sample ubuntu-htmui project, no .qml file is being created as explained in the tutorial. Not even app.js file is being created.

My QT Creater version is 2.8.1 and it is based on qt 5.0.2

This screenshot shows my project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 app development support is under rapid development now. This means the content on developer.ubuntu.com is outdated fairly quickly. I am sorry for the confusion this causes.

If you install/update the Ubuntu SDK from the Ubunu SDK Released PPA, there is now a single type of HTML5 app project available (there used to be two types). This single type does not need or use a qml file, and it automatically creates an js/app.js file for you.

Answer (score 0):

PS: you can run the project from command line directly like this:

```
$ ubuntu-html5-app-launcher $@ --www=www
```